# getExpoPushTokenAsync not working in expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, expo

I am using expo react-native with firebase using the expo-notifications library.
I am trying to log users to Notifications using getExpoPushTokenAsync with the project id as such:

```
 const expoPushToken = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({
   projectId: 'your-project-id',
  });
```

yet, it still return a VALIDATION_EROR with a prompt of projectId must be a valid GUID
Does anyone seem to know what the problem is with what I'm doing?

I tried:

```
 const expoPushToken = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({
   projectId: 'your-project-id',
  });
```

and expected to recieve the correct token and instead got VALIDATION_ERROR

Answer (score 8):

The error indicates that the given id is not valid. You should replace 'your-project-id' with your **expo** project id.

You can find this id in your expo account : [https://expo.dev/accounts/[ACCOUNT_NAME]/projects](https://expo.dev/accounts/%5BACCOUNT_NAME%5D/projects). Select your project and at the top of the overview page you should see your project id.

e.g. b77530dc-352b-424f-f730-8300f975178b (this is a fake id)

To get the expo token you then use this id as follows :

```
expoPushToken = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({
   projectId: 'b77530dc-352b-424f-f730-8300f975178b',
})).data;
console.log(expoPushToken);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Expo EAS to build your app, you might want to have the app autodetect the `projectId` so that you don't have to hard code it. You can do that with the following code:

```
import Constants from "expo-constants"

const expoPushToken = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({
  projectId: Constants.expoConfig.extra.eas.projectId,
});
```

More details for setup can be found [here](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/push-notifications-setup/#configure-projectid).

Answer (score 0):

For project id, you need to first create an expo project on https://expo.dev/ .After that you can get the project id from the created project just like below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TTsP.png)